# useState set does not update right away in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have one question regarding to my customized `useCallBack` that I really have no idea how I should fix it. Under my hook `useValueChange`, I use one local variable `prevValue` to store the state of input value from hook. the logic is if `prevValue` object does not match with updateValue object. go to the if/else logic and then update `prevValue`. The issue I have are

1. useCallBack block still run even `JSON.stringify(updateValue)` does not change
2. setPrevValue does not update `prevValue` right away. as useState runs async
   so wheneve I call the hook multiple time even updateValue does not change, the apicall `updateValueApiCall` trigger consistently
   any idea how I should fix?

```
function useValueChange(updatedValue) {
  const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState<ValueQueryVariables>({name: '', address: '', info:{a: '', b''}});

  const onValueChange = useCallback(async (): Promise<void> => {
    const isValueUpdate = !isEqual(prevValue, updateValue);

    if (isValueUpdate) {
      console.log({updatedValue, prevValue});
      setPrevValue(() => updatedValue);
      await updateValueApiCall({...updatedValue});
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(updateValue)]);
  return {onValueChange};
}

//component Level

const App: FC = (props) => {
    const {inputValue} = props
    const {onValueChange} = useValueChange(inputValue)
    const handleOnClick = useCallBack(() =>{
        onValueChange()
    })
    return (
        <div><button onClick={handleOnClick}>click</button></div>
    )
}
```

## Update

after some research, thinking to use effect try to make it update. but I still do not get it work.

all suggestions are welcome

```
function useValueChange(updatedValue) {
  const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState<ValueQueryVariables>({name: '', address: '', info:{a: '', b''}});
  const [isUpdate, setUpdate] = useState(false);

  const onValueChange = useCallback(async (): Promise<void> => {
    const isValueUpdate = !isEqual(prevValue, updateValue);
    setUpdate(isValueUpdate)

    if (isValueUpdate) {
      console.log({updatedValue, prevValue});
      setPrevValue(() => updatedValue);
      await updateValueApiCall({...updatedValue});
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(updateValue)]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (isUpdate){
        setPrevValue(updateValue)
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(updateValue), isUpdate, setUpdate])
  return {onValueChange};
}
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior. State will always be the same throughout a render cycle, the new values will be available on the next render. If you need to react to state change, either store an interim value in a variable, use it, and then setState; or add the state to the dependency array of a useEffect to trigger actions on change.

Comment: @pilchard possible to provide some example?

Comment: in component Level `handleOnClick ` not equal `onValueChange` it equal the first value of it, because you use it inside  `useCallBack`, so you need to remove  `handleOnClick = useCallBack(() =>  onValueChange())` and use onValueChange directly

Comment: @AhmedGaber i cannt, I only want to trigger to hook `useValueChange` when I click the button